# Character not developing with DM's story

Tags: pathfinder-1e, problem-players, problem-gm

I haven't RPed much, only 2-3 games; most of them are never completed due to events happening and the RP can't be continued.

In the current game I have made a Chaotic Neutral character, whose main goal is to search for treasure and likes to plan his steps. My DM is currently expecting all characters to go along with the quest for the fact that is the right thing to do, or heroic act. My character does not see a reason to follow with the quest, making the DM provide exp to the members following this quest while I'm left with nothing. I am not sure what the best choice to make with this. Should I break out of character and just follow with the story or make a new character that aligns with the DM's purpose?

Comment: Related question that every gamer should read: [What is My Guy syndrome, and how do I handle it?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37103/15469)

Comment: Frankly I think the part of this question that isn't opinion-based is answered by the question Miniman links.  I'm closing as duplicate for the time being, if you investigate that and then can edit your question to be more objectively answerable, we'll reopen.

Comment: No the link help, thanks. Never knew there was a term for it though.